# Stargazer ARIMA package in rmarkdown showing full output

Tags: r-markdown, arima, stargazer

I'm trying to generate a PDF with rmarkdown, using stargazer to present some models using the ARIMA package. The table looks beautiful, but there is a lot of output above in the final PDF.

[image]

I've tried a few chunk options (message=F, comment=F, header=F) and none get rid of this output. Using  results="hide" gets rid of the final table as well.

The final code I'm using is:

````
```
```{r 1_b_ii, results='asis', echo=F}
stargazer(m, title="Fitting an AR(0) regression to DemHouseMaj",
          type = 'latex',
          nobs=T,
          digits=2,
          single.row=T,
          dep.var.caption  = "Democratic House Majority",
          dep.var.labels   = "Coefficient (Standard Error)",
          header=F) ```
```
````

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example that we can run?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `forecast` package loaded? If you do, restart your R session and run your code chunk before you load the `forecast` package. I'm not sure why, but summarizing `arima()` models in stargazer is affected by `forecast`.